# Automatic line breaking and \hfill

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I work on a CV and I would like to write some content (e.g. conference information) on the left side of the page and a date on the right side of the page.

Because the content on the left side might be too long for one line: Is there a way to implement automatic line breaking while keeping the date after \hfill in the first line irrespective of how long the content on the left side is?

My example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\begin{document}

{\Large \bf Conferences}

\centerline{Line 1, Line 1, Line 1, Line 1, Line 1, Line 1, Line 1, Line 1, Line 1, \hfill \textbf{Date}}
\centerline{Line 2. \hfill}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to avoid using a second `\centerline{}`?

I prefer not using tables or CV templates.

I use MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your own environment for this. There's space for improvements; for instance, you might want that the space reserved on the right is fixed for all items.

The `\lipsum` paragraphs are just to show how the environment's content is typeset with respect to the page margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\datumlen}
\newenvironment{datum}[1]
 {\settowidth\datumlen{\textbf{#1}}%
  \addtolength\datumlen{2em}% padding
  \list{}{\rightmargin=\datumlen\leftmargin=0pt}
  \item\relax\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\textbf{#1}}}\ignorespaces}
 {\endlist}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{datum}{2013}
Some text describing what I want to describe, that will be
justified and automatically broken across lines, with space
reserved for the date on the right, which is printed
in boldface.
\end{datum}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a series of items, you can do like the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\datumlen}
\newenvironment{data}[1]
 {\settowidth\datumlen{\textbf{#1}}%
  \addtolength\datumlen{2em}% padding
  \list{}{\rightmargin=\datumlen\leftmargin=0pt}}
 {\endlist}

\newcommand\dataitem[1]{%
  \item\relax\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\textbf{#1}}}\ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{data}{2013--current}% the argument is the widest label

\dataitem{2012} Some text describing what I want to describe, that will
be justified and automatically broken across lines, with space
reserved for the date on the right, which is printed in boldface.

\dataitem{2013--current} Again other text that should be broken across
lines and leave the correct amount of space on the right.
\end{data}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a follow up question based on your solution.

I tried to expand the code above to achieve a structure like

    `\begin{datum}{widest date width}`
    `\item{text 1}{date 1}`
    `\item{text 2}{date 2}`
    `\end{datum}`

Text 1 and text 2 are meant to break automatically.

It might be more flexible to define a new \item command instead of a new environment in order to avoid typing \begin{datum}{date} and \end{datum} again and again. However, I could not make it work.

Comment: @Matzipan I added the multiple item version

Comment: Now it is exactly what I need, so thank you again.